# Showing that $\mathrm{P}(t,x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathrm{G}_t(x-2\pi n)\in\mathbb{C}^\infty((0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Welcome everybody :)

I need your help in answering the following question:

---

Let $t > 0$ and $\mathrm{G}_t(x) = (2\pi t)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2t}$
Show that $$\mathrm{P}(t,x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathrm{G}_t(x-2\pi n)$$

is a smooth function on $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$, i.e. an element of $\mathbb{C}^\infty((0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$.

---

Somebody has told me that this $\mathrm{G}_t$ is called the *Gauss-Weierstrass kernel*.

I have two approaches to show the task:

a) use the *Weierstrass M-Test*
b) use the *Poisson summation formula*

However I'm not sure if there's another approach using complex analysis (Morera's Theorem).

My aim here is to ask some tough guys about their opinion how to solve this task and more preferable posting a solution if possible.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Hi there
Thank you for the second link, I really wanted to adjust the spacing in my answer and now I will work through this.
Is your advice concerning the MathJax stuff because the question isn't displayed properly?
As far as I know the unicode symbols should be displayed correct, at least on (firefox, IE) both on my tablet and smartphone.
Is it about the $ℂ,ℝ$ or the italic-like appearance of the symbols if i use $?